# What is the correct character entity reference syntax?

Tags: java

Hi i want to get é symbol in 
XSLT , for that i am  using String description=Log&#233 in java code . but after setting to method # symbol is missing.

```
if (!(StringHelper.isBlankOrNull(hotelInfo.getTextInfo()))) {

    String description="Log&#233" ;

    setSessionDataXML(TAG_HOTEL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, description);

    System.out.println("String Value"+TAG_HOTEL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT);
}
```

its printing log& 233

please help me to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is missing, try:

```
String description="Log&#233;";
```